# String was not recognised as valid date time

Tags: c#, string, datetime

How can I convert this date `02-12-2013` to `02/12/2013`. Getting the error:

> String was not recognised as valid DateTime.

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
table.Rows.Add(
   25,
   "Indocin",
   "David",
   DateTime.ParseExact("02-12-2013", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
);
```

Comment: If `-` is your date-separator you just have to omit `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. The `/` will be replaced with your current culture's date-separator as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator).

Answer (score 1):

Use `dd-MM-yyyy` format instead of `dd/MM/yyyy`.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly**

In your case, clearly they are not.

I suspect if your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `-`, you can skip to use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) part. You can use it as a `null` which is equal to use [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[`"/"` Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning in custom date and time format. It means as; *replace me with the current culture date separator or specified culture*.

And next time, please read documentation carefully.

> but here I have scenario where the date can be in any formats like
>   dd-MM-yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy or MM-dd/yyyy formats or it could be any but
>   I need to show output only as dd/MM/yyyy format only. Please suggest

First of all, `DateTime` doesn't have any implicit format. It just a value. `String` representation of it can have a format.

If your string can have multiple formats, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact(String, String\[\], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes a string array as your formats. Then you can use [`DateTime.ToString(format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to show your `DateTime` what ever format you want like;

```
yourDateTime.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy");
```

Comment: but here I have scenario where the date can be in any formats like dd-MM-yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy or MM-dd/yyyy formats or it could be any but I need to show output only as dd/MM/yyyy format only. Please suggest

Comment: @user1030181: Well that's not what your question asks... and if it can  be `MM-dd-yyyy` or `dd-MM-yyyy` what do you expect the result to be for `06-07-2014` for example. Is that June 7th or July 6th?

Comment: @user1030181 Jon is right (of course). If you use both `MM-dd-yyyy` and `dd-MM-yyyy` formats in your array, `DateTime.ParseExact(.., string[], ..)` overload chooses first formats that fits with your string. That means, if you write your `dd-MM-yyyy` format before your `MM-dd-yyyy` in array definition, your `06/07/2014` value parsed as `dd/MM/yyyy` format and it will be _July 6th_.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
string format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.ParseExact("02-12-2013", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: but here I have scenario where the date can be in any formats like dd-MM-yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy or MM-dd/yyyy formats or it could be any but I need to show output only as dd/MM/yyyy format only. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Hope that you want to format the date; if you don't mind make the following change in your code:

```
System.DateTime dates = Now.Date;
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David",dates.ToString(format) ));
```